# How do I avoid `ErrImagePull` when using Kubernetes file, local docker image and `kubectl apply`?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this that is working...

```
# Set docker env
eval $(minikube docker-env)

# Build image
docker build -t jrg/hw .

# Run in minikube
kubectl run hello-world --image=jrg/hw:latest --image-pull-policy=Never --port=8080
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=hello-service
```

I can access the endpoint just as I expect. Now I am trying to use a .yml file to deploy like this...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world-dev
  labels:
    purpose: simple
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello-world-dev-container
    image: jrg/hw:latest
    env:
    - name: WORKING
      value: "Yup Working"
```

But when I run `kubectl apply -f k8s/ineject/dev.envvars.yml` I get...

```
NAME                           READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
hello-world-7d87b8ddd5-gqr8k   1/1     Running        1          2d22h
hello-world-dev                0/1     ErrImagePull   0          6s
```

So why can one see my local docker to get the image and 1 has an issue?

Comment: Your YAML file doesn't specify `imagePullPolicy: Never`, but you manual `kubectl run` command has the equivalent command-line option.  For a `...:latest` image tag, [it defaults to `Always`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images).

Answer (score 0):

In the docs regarding [Pre-pulling Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulling-images) we can read:

> By default, the kubelet will try to pull each image from the specified registry. However, if the `imagePullPolicy` property of the container is set to `IfNotPresent` or `Never`, then a local image is used (preferentially or exclusively, respectively).

Also please see other options with `imagePullPolicy` in [Container Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images) docs.

> The  [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)  and the tag of the image affect when the  [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)  attempts to pull the specified image.
>
> - `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`: the image is pulled only if it is not already present locally.
> - `imagePullPolicy: Always`: the image is pulled every time the pod is started.
> - `imagePullPolicy`  is omitted and either the image tag is  `:latest`  or it is omitted:  `Always`  is applied.
> - `imagePullPolicy`  is omitted and the image tag is present but not  `:latest`:  `IfNotPresent`  is applied.
> - `imagePullPolicy: Never`: the image is assumed to exist locally. No attempt is made to pull the image.